# R - equivalent function to 'length' with O(log(n)) complexity

Tags: r, loops, time-complexity

I need to write an equivalent function to the function `length` -without using 
`length`, of course. also it must be using a loop.

I need to write two versions for this function. the first, with O(n) complexity, and the second need to be in O(log(n))

**EDIT**

Also,  Suppose that the vector doesn't contain `NA` values

**My Attempt:**

```
my_length_l <- function(x){
  k <- 1
  while(!is.na(x[k])){
  k <- k+1
  }
 return(k-1)
}
```

for `my_length_l`:

T(n) = O(n)

**second version:**

```
my_length_bs <- function(x){
  if(is.na(x[2])){return(1)}
  else
    {
  k <- 2
  for(i in 1:log2(2^k)){
  while(!is.na(x[k])){
  k <- k+1
  }
  }
    }
 return(k-1)
}
```

Is `my_length_bs` indeed exists T(n) = log(n)?

Comment: I don't think the logic for checking for NA to determine length is a good idea. Vectors in R can contain missing values. Compare: `x<-c(1, NA, 3, 4, 5); my_length_l(x); length(x)`

Comment: yes, your'e correct, but for this case we assume the vector doesn't contain NA values

Comment: Your second version doesn't make much sense. You hard-wire in `k = 2` and then have the loop `for(i in 1:log2(2^k)`. Isn't that just `for(i in 1:2)`?

Comment: @JohnColeman but the matter is that i need to make the function in O(log(n))

Comment: @Jneven why'd you delete your 5000 digit number question? I was just about to answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer you immediate question, your second function is just an obfuscated version of your first. The outer for-loop is executed exactly twice and doesn't really do anything, and the inner while loop (which essentially *is* your first function) does all the work.To see this, put the line `print(k)` just before `k <- k+1` in the inner loop. Then if e.g. you evaluate `my_length_bs(1:15)` you will see the numbers 2,3,4,...,15 printed in turn. It is still `O(n)`. You need to do a genuine binary search. First go up by powers of 2 until you overshoot the end of the array, and then do a binary search from that starting point to find the actual end of the array.